Как вывести весь массив Python?
json:
{
  "users": [
    {
      "fullname": "osos",
      "phone": "ksksk",
      "email": "амогус"
    },
    {
      "fullname": "ггыгы",
      "phone": "пфылпф",
      "email": "ылылыл"
    }
  ]
}

python:
import json
import string

slovo = input()
with open('uchiru.json.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            if slovo in line:
                print(line)

Найдя схожее слово, мне нужно вывести весь массив, а не строку, как это сделать?

Что такое "массив"? Приведите пример. И раз данные уже организованы, вот и работайте с джейсоном.

import json
import string

def check_key_in_json(file_path, key):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        if key in data:
            return data[key]
        else:
            return "Ключ не найден."

    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "Файл не найден."
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        return "Ошибка декодирования JSON."

slovo = input('Введите ключ ')
print(check_key_in_json('uchiru.json', slovo))

Запустим программу и посмотрим вывод.
python main.py
Введите ключ users
[{'fullname': 'osos', 'phone': 'ksksk', 'email': 'амогус'}, {'fullname': 'ггыгы', 'phone': 'пфылпф', 'email': 'ылылыл'}]

